# Bash script OS detect and if and wget

Tags: bash, shell, sh

Bash script OS detect and  if and wget problem. I tried os bit detect itself and it work normaly.
Edit: I found that was space after every "fi"
Ful bash  http://pastebin.com/ENVYmXsU
But now i get unexpected end of file.

Edit: I copied same text from pastebin i copied to pastebin and now it works. How is that possible ? Pastebin add extra empty lines This is orig file http://www57.zippyshare.com/v/15049778/file.html

I keep getting

```
[root@localhost ~]# sh ioncube.sh
: command not found 
ioncube.sh: line 28: syntax error near unexpected token `fi'
'oncube.sh: line 28: `fi
```

The code:

```
if [ `getconf LONG_BIT` = "64" ]
then

  # 64-bit stuff here

wget http://downloads3.ioncube.com/loader_downloads/ioncube_loaders_lin_x86-64.tar.gz

else

  # 32-bit stuff here

wget http://downloads3.ioncube.com/loader_downloads/ioncube_loaders_lin_x86.tar.gz

fi
```

Comment: Can you post the original file somewhere? You might have a newline problem.

Comment: I copied same text from pastebin i copied to pastebin and now it works. How is that possible ? Pastebin add extra empty lines This is orig file http://www57.zippyshare.com/v/15049778/file.html

Comment: You must have had Windows newlines in the file. It's a common problem when using Windows editors for *nix shell scripts.

Answer (score 0):

I think we would need to see **line 28** of the script; as that's where the error occurred; you have only posted 14 lines, and which comprise only a single control statement and two commands. FWIW, that code looks' like it should run, although you may wish to put the URI's in "quotes", incase they contain unusual characters.

Comment: Original code work normaly
http://www.scriptuse.com/ioncube-automated-installation-with-bash-script/
And yes is chmod +x file.sh and chmod 755 file.sh

Comment: It runs fine on my system. Do you have all the utility it calls installed, and accessible in your path? wget, getconf, php, etc? Otherwise, all that script does is download those url, and then write out a tiny config file that I'm sure you could find elsewhere. You could just download the packages in your browser and untar them yourself...

Comment: Which one work ? my edited from pastebingon from scriptuse.com ?

From that site it work
I checked with WinMerge and i don't find anything changed except thos added code.

Comment: What the heck. I copied same text from pastebin i copied to pastebin and now it works. How is that possible ? Pastebin add extra empty lines

This is orig file http://www57.zippyshare.com/v/15049778/file.html

Answer (score 0):

You must have had Windows newlines in the file. It's a common problem when using Windows editors for *nix shell scripts. – l0b0